# Assessing a Function's Argument Types From Tuple

Tags: typescript, function, types, arguments

I am trying to use tuple type as function argument's type.

```js
type T_a = (a1: string, a2: number) => boolean
const a: T_a = (a1, a2) => a1.length >= a2

type T_b_arguments = [number, string]
type T_b = (...T_b_arguments) => boolean
const b: T_b = (b1, b2) => b1 < b2.length

// Example:
b(1, 'mystring) // true
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=42&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg%20gQygXigCgQRgFxQM7ABOAlgHYDmANFAgEy6kCuAtgEYSECUKAfFKwHsBAGwgJSAKADGA0gRq54SVBkzU63ZHywA6URWAALKD1R0JE0JFhxWiQuRYRSwPCigBtJmw7UCJCgBdS3BoeFZ3NB1o8PtHZmdXTT5BETFJGTlgfkVbSNY1flpk-kwoAB4ivWdyIyA)

How can I do this?

Comment: `(...T_b_arguments) => boolean` is equivalent to `(...T_b_arguments: any) => boolean`. Parameter names are required in all contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function's formal parameters are defined as `parameter_name` followed  by an optional type annotation. That is `name` or `name: type annotation`

If no type annotation is specified and none can be inferred, the parameter will have type `any`.

In the case of a rest parameter, written `...parameter`, if no type annotation is specified and none can be inferred, `...parameter` will have type `any[]`.

Therefore, in the

```
type T_b = (...T_b_arguments) => boolean
```

`T_b_arguments` does not refer to a type but is the name of a rest parameter of type `any[]`

To correct this, you must name the parameter and apply the type annotation, `T_b_arguments`

```
type T_b = (...args: T_b_arguments) => boolean
```

Note that the `...` syntax is not applied to the parameter type but to the parameter name.

Here is the fully working code

```
type T_a = (a1: string, a2: number) => boolean
const a: T_a = (a1, a2) => a1.length >= a2

type T_b_arguments = [number, string]
type T_b = (...args: T_b_arguments) => boolean
const b: T_b = (b1, b2) => b1 < b2.length

b(1, 'mystring') // true
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg+gQygXigCgQRgFxQM7ABOAlgHYDmANFAgEy6kCuAtgEYSECUKAfFKwHsBAGwgJSAKADGA0gRq54SVBkzU63ZHywA6URWAALKD1R0JE0JFhxWiQuRYRSwPCigBtJmw7UCJCgBdS3BoeFZ3NB1ohAc8RVt7R2ZnV00+QRExSRk5YH4EiJVWNX5adP5MKAAeMr1nciMLVjRSgHJmEH8ycjbuAHp+qCJGCCA)

Comment: Thank you! Maybe my explaination are a bit sketchy but this is exactly it!